# Mongo group by Week is wrong time?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm using aggregate with group to calculate max value of hours, days, or weeks.
And everything is very well with hours, days. But have some issues with weeks group.
For detail, I have a record of day: 2020-06-03 and that day belong to week 23 of 2020 ( week 23 from 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-07 ) but mongo is return the value of 2020-06-03 to week 22 of 2020

Sample: ( You can see at here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/T9LeA7jpNLa )

This is my mock recording:

```
[
  {
    "dateTime": ISODate("2020-06-03"),
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "dateTime": ISODate("2020-05-25"),
    "value": 27
  }
]
```

And this is my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "dateTime": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2020-05-01"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-07-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "week": {
          "$week": {
            "date": "$dateTime",
            "timezone": "+00:00"
          }
        },
        "year": {
          "$year": {
            "date": "$dateTime",
            "timezone": "+00:00"
          }
        }
      },
      "maxValue": {
        "$max": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "start": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
              }
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        },
        "end": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$dateFromParts": {
                    "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                    "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
                  }
                },
                518400000
              ]
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        }
      },
      "maxValue": "$maxValue"
    }
  }
])
```

And result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "end": "2020-05-24",
      "start": "2020-05-18"
    },
    "maxValue": 27
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "end": "2020-05-31",
      "start": "2020-05-25"
    },
    "maxValue": 25
  }
]
```

My expect:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "end": "2020-05-31",
      "start": "2020-05-25"
    },
    "maxValue": 27
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "end": "2020-06-01",
      "start": "2020-06-07"
    },
    "maxValue": 25
  }
]
```

Comment: What is a "week" in your application? Perhaps you are looking for https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isoWeek/#mongodb-expression-exp.-isoWeek

Comment: Oh I missed your comment, your right. I'm using $week to get number of week but use isoWeek to build date so I think it's not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exactly answer is I used wrong operator. In $group stage, I used $week and $year but in $project stage I used $isoWeek and $isoWeekYear. It make conflict with the value #week of year, I need only be updated $week and $year in group stage to $isoWeek and $isoWeekYear.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "dateTime": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2020-05-01"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-07-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "week": {
          "$isoWeek": {
            "date": "$dateTime",
            "timezone": "+00:00"
          }
        },
        "year": {
          "$isoWeekYear": {
            "date": "$dateTime",
            "timezone": "+00:00"
          }
        }
      },
      "maxValue": {
        "$max": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "start": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
              }
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        },
        "end": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$dateFromParts": {
                    "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                    "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
                  }
                },
                518400000
              ]
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        }
      },
      "maxValue": "$maxValue"
    }
  }
])db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "dateTime": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2020-05-01"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-07-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "week": {
          "$week": {
            "date": "$dateTime",
            "timezone": "+00:00"
          }
        },
        "year": {
          "$year": {
            "date": "$dateTime",
            "timezone": "+00:00"
          }
        }
      },
      "maxValue": {
        "$max": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "start": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
              }
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        },
        "end": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$dateFromParts": {
                    "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                    "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
                  }
                },
                518400000
              ]
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
          }
        }
      },
      "maxValue": "$maxValue"
    }
  }
])
```

ref: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qTk3Opm9D3W

Answer (score 0):

From [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/#-week--aggregation-),

> Returns the week of the year for a date as a number between 0 and 53.

> Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. This behavior is the same as the "%U" operator to the strftime standard library function.

the week number is zero-based instead of one-based that we used in common life.

So for your case in 2020, week 0 should be 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-05 and week 1 should be 2020-01-06 to 2020-01-12. This also explains for week 53, which is 2020-12-27 to 2020-12-31.

As identified by OP, the aggregation should be changed to use `$isoWeek`.

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yyxxdk-zFo-)

Comment: that is a conflict of mongo ?  Because I see value of isoWeek in range 1-53, if I add 1 to week, what if it was week 53 (+1 = 54)?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/

Comment: If exactly, $week return value between 0 - 52. Right ?

Comment: @VũAnhDũng thanks for your curiousity! I updated my answer with more quotes from the offical doc to explain for week 0 and week 53.

Comment: It’s mean week 0 is a part of week 53 or 2019. What if it was first monday is first day of year. We’ll don’t have week 0?

Comment: Following the definition, "first monday is first day of year" should count as week 0; as they are before the first sunday of the year. You may try for 2024-01-01 to observe the result. For the first sunday is exacly the first day of year, there is no week 0 as it already start with week 1. You may verify with 2023-01-01 for this case

Comment: Yes, I mean if first Sunday is first day of year, then adding offset 1 week is wrong. Because that year don't have week 0. I tried on your query with data at 2023-01-01 and result is not correct, 2023-01-01 but return week 2. https://mongoplayground.net/p/VsqK_y8EBFu

Comment: And you can see here (https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZKHHRhC3a8J), if not add 1 week offset, 2023-01-01 is always belong to week 1 of 2023, it should be in week 52 of 2022

Comment: you are right. I have updated the playground link to add the offset depending on whether there is week 0 for the year

Comment: Thanks @ray. But as my above comment, still have an issue that is 2023-01-01 is belongs to week 1 of 2023 ( from 2023-01-02 to 2023-01-08 ). I tried on your newest mongo play background and still happening. https://mongoplayground.net/p/SXrDUDmJqg4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235433/discussion-between-ray-and-v-anh-dng).